# Is there a structured way to reference function parameter labels in Python docstring?

Tags: python, pydoc

I am using the tool [pydoc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html) to automatically generate documentation. Given the function:

```
def sum(a, b):
  """Returns the sum of a and b."""
  return a + b
```

I am curious if there is a structured way to use markdown to highlight references to function parameter labels? For example:

```
"""Returns the sum of 'a' and 'b'."""
"""Returns the sum of `a` and `b."""
"""Returns the sum of *a* and *b*."""
"""Returns the sum of **a** and **b**."""
```

Similar to this question [Referencing parameters in a Python docstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879717/referencing-parameters-in-a-python-docstring) which is about using Sphinx instead of pydoc.

Also note, that I am curious about referencing the labels (not the types) of the function parameters.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690220/how-to-document-python-function-parameter-types, check this url.

Comment: @LavanyaPant, thanks. The question you linked discusses how to annotate the type of the parameter, which I'm not really interested in. I'm more curious about a standard way to reference the label of the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no markdown support in Pydoc.

Formatting in docstrings is limited to [recognising PEP and RFC references, `self.` attribute references and links for existing names (for other classes, methods, and functions) when rendering to HTML](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1bf9cc509326bc42cd8cb1650eb9bf64550d817e/Lib/pydoc.py#L588-L627), so in in that mode, some names are already going to be marked up. This doesn't extend to argument names however.

Pydoc does use [`inspect.signature()` output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) as the basis for formatting the function, so if you make sure you have [informative type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), then you'll at least get to document the types of the arguments and return value.

So a (rather contrived) definition using a generic `TypeVar` definition instead of sticking to `float`, like:

```
from typing import TypeVar

Number = TypeVar('Number', int, float)

def sum(a: Number, b: Number) -> Number:
    """Produce the sum of the two numbers, a and b"""
    return a + b
```

comes out in pydoc as

```
sum(a: ~Number, b: ~Number) -> ~Number
    Produce the sum of the two numbers, a and b
```

Comment: Cool, that makes a lot of sense. Now I'm trying to remember why I thought Pydoc supported markdown, weird.

Comment: You might have been thinking of `pydoc-markdown`.  To be charitable, it is miserable piece of software that does not deliver what the name suggests.